# trying to write code to check source of webpage for certain metrics

Tags: html, web-applications

I'm trying to write some code that will check a certain webpage for a metric. Does anyone know of any good tutorials or examples which call on a certain page, and checks for a metric? I would be looking through a table for the current date and checking the impressions metric (see code) This is just the first row but, but I would need to find the current date in the table and find the next "td-impr" class and check what the metric is. I already know how to get the current date in that format, just don't know how to call a page and get to this specific part of the table.

```
<div id="contentBody" class="flexcroll" style="height: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
<table class="prod">
<tr>
    <td class="td-date">05/06/13</td>
    <td class="td-impr">0</td>
    <td class="td-clicks">0</td>
    <td class="td-ctr">0%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are web site parsing libraries out there. I used JSoup (at http://jsoup.org/) for Java to parse the IBM information center and was successful. There are examples for table parsing everywhere, like at [how to parse a table from HTML using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396098/how-to-parse-a-table-from-html-using-jsoup).

Since the question is about parsing HTML in PHP: I personally never used such a PHP library. However [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) may help.

Comment: Are there any solutions using Javascript/html/php? I have never used java before.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link that may help. I don't have experience with a PHP library.