# JSoup how to parse table 3 rows

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a table like this that i want to Parse to get the data-code value of `row.id` and the second and third column of the table.

```
<table>
    <tr class="id" data-code="100">
       <td></td>
       <td>18</td>
       <td class="name">John</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr class="id" data-code="200">
       <td></td>
       <td>21</td>
       <td class="name">Mark</td>
    <tr/>
</table>
```

I want to print out.

```
100, 18, John
200, 21, Mark
```

I have tried the following suggestion from this thread but its not selecting anything  [how to parse a table from HTML using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396098/how-to-parse-a-table-from-html-using-jsoup)

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.myurl.com");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

Element tables = doc.select("table[class=id]");

for(Element table : tables)
{
     System.out.println(table.toString());
}
```

EDIT: also tried using Jsoup.connect() instead of parse()

```
Document doc = null;
try
{
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myurl.com").get();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Table doesn't have a class "id"...? Try tr[class=id]

Comment: it doesnt work and i have tried `doc.select("table tr.id")` and `"table tr[class=id]")`

Comment: Works fine here... error is probably in the first two lines... does println(doc) output anything?

Comment: it doesnt print anything for me

Comment: Does the link show anything when you put it in your browser?

Comment: Yes, it loads a table in firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.myurl.com");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
// This should work now
Element tables = doc.select("table tr .id");
// This propably should work too
Element tables2 = doc.select("table tr[class*=id]");

for(Element table : tables)
{
     System.out.println(table.toString());
}
```

From documentation:

> public Elements select(String cssQuery) Find elements that match the
>   Selector CSS query, with this element as the starting context. Matched
>   elements may include this element, or any of its children.  This
>   method is generally more powerful to use than the DOM-type
>   getElementBy* methods, because multiple filters can be combined, e.g.:
>   •el.select("a[href]") - finds links (a tags with href attributes) 
>   •el.select("a[href*=example.com]") - finds links pointing to
>   example.com (loosely)
>
> See the query syntax documentation in Selector.
>
> Parameters: cssQuery - a Selector CSS-like query Returns: elements
>   that match the query (empty if none match)

Comment: Thank you it works. how do i get the text in between `<td class="name">John</td>`

Comment: doc.select("table tr .id td").text(); I thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396098/how-to-parse-a-table-from-html-using-jsoup Try to find answer there